# Autocomplete textbox based on querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I have created an autocomplete textbox using ajax which works brilliantly. It basically provides a list of rooms code. Here is the code:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetRoomList(string prefixText, int count)
{
  using (SqlConnection roomsConnection = new SqlConnection())
  {
     roomsConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["roomsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     using (SqlCommand roomsCommand = new SqlCommand())
     {
        roomsCommand.CommandText = "select Room, Site from tblRoom where Room like '%' + @SearchText + '%'";
        roomsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
        roomsCommand.Connection = roomsConnection;
        roomsConnection.Open();

        List<string> roomList = new List<string>();
        using (SqlDataReader roomReader = roomsCommand.ExecuteReader())
          {
              while (roomReader.Read())
              {
                  roomList.Add(roomReader["Room"].ToString());
              }
           }
           roomsConnection.Close();
           return roomList;
       }
    }
}
```

However I'd like it produce this list of room codes based on an option that a user selects on the previous page. There are 2 ways in which an option can be passed. One is to use a querystring. This is the code I have written:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetRoomList(string prefixText, int count)
{
   using (SqlConnection roomsConnection = new SqlConnection())
   {
       roomsConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["roomsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

       HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
       string site1 = request.QueryString["site"];

       using (SqlCommand roomsCommand = new SqlCommand())
       {
          roomsCommand.CommandText = "select Room, Site from tblRoom where Site = '" + site1 + "' AND Room like '%' + @SearchText + '%'";
          roomsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
          roomsCommand.Connection = roomsConnection;
          roomsConnection.Open();

          List<string> roomList = new List<string>();
          using (SqlDataReader roomReader = roomsCommand.ExecuteReader())
          {
             while (roomReader.Read())
               {
                   roomList.Add(roomReader["Room"].ToString());
               }
          }
          return roomList;
          roomsConnection.Close();
     }                    
   }             
 }
```

I'm not getting any errors with this it's just not storing 'site' from the querystring. I have used this in other areas of my page and it works fine.

The other way I'd like it to work is to use a Page.PreviousPage. Again this is what I have written:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetRoomList(string prefixText, int count)
{
   using (SqlConnection roomsConnection = new SqlConnection())
     {
        roomsConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["roomsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
        {
            if (Page.PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack == true)
            {
                string site1 = PreviousPage.getDropDownListSite.SelectedValue;

                using (SqlCommand roomsCommand = new SqlCommand())
                {
                        roomsCommand.CommandText = "select Room, Site from tblRoom where Site = '" + site1 + "' AND Room like '%' + @SearchText + '%'";
                        roomsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                        roomsCommand.Connection = roomsConnection;
                        roomsConnection.Open();

                        List<string> roomList = new List<string>();
                        using (SqlDataReader roomReader = roomsCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (roomReader.Read())
                            {
                                roomList.Add(roomReader["Room"].ToString());
                            }
                        }
               return roomList;
               roomsConnection.Close();
               }           
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I cannot get this code to work at all as it doesn't like Page.PreviousPage. I am getting the error

```
An object reference is required for the non-static filed, method, or property      'system.Web.UI.Page.PreviousPage.get'
```

But I can't work out what else to use. I have tried using a session variable which worked great but if I user needs to use the form again in the same session it's holding onto the last value.

I intend to us a if, else statement once I have the individual components working.

Can anyone help with this. I'd really appreciate it.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way than fetching the querystring parameter inside the webmethod, is to transfer the the parameter as a parameter to your webmethod:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetRoomList(string prefixText, int count, string site)
{
    ...
}
```

On the calling page, you have to set the querystring to the contextKey in the Page_Load function. the contextKey can be tranfered to the web method so that you can access this varible inside the webmethod.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. That was just what I needed. I'm sorry it's taken a while to reply but I was away. That has really helped me out. I really appreciate it. Thank you.